# Are there any open source inverse-based multilevel ILU implementations?

Tags: pde, algorithms, linear-solver, libraries, preconditioning

I am very impressed with the serial performance of [multilevel inverse-based ILU preconditioners](http://www.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/umsi-2004-75.pdf), particularly for [heterogeneous Helmholtz](http://epubs.siam.org/sisc/resource/1/sjoce3/v31/i5/p3781_s1), but I am surprised to not be able to find any open source implementations. In particular, [ILUPACK](http://www.icm.tu-bs.de/~bolle/ilupack/) makes binaries freely available to academics, but it does not appear that they release their source code.

Is it really the case that no one has open sourced their implementation?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/linearsolvertable.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Yousef Saad's package of iterative solvers [ITSOL](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/ITSOL/index.html)? It includes another library called the Algebraic Recursive Multilevel Solver [pARMS](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/pARMS/index.html), which I'm pretty sure is what you're talking about; Saad is the author of the paper you linked.

There's also [Euclid](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~pothen/Software/Euclid/), which PETSc can interface to, but I don't think Euclid works in a multilevel fashion like pARMS.

Comment: Unfortunately ITSOL does *not* include the algorithms I am referring to. And Said is *an* author of the paper, the other author, Bollhoefer, was the developer of ILUPACK.

Comment: Woops! I looked up ILUPACK after posting and saw that they're not the same.